# Is there an efficient way for intermediate calculations in Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, refactoring

I have this query which uses LinqToEntities behind the scenes.

```
(...)
.GroupBy(x => x.FahrerID)
.Select(x => new FahrerligaEintrag()
{
    FahrerID = x.Key,
    FahrerFullName = string.Empty,
    VollgasKmAufHundertKm = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter)) * (x.Sum(y => y.Gas100ProzentInMeter.Value) + x.Sum(y => y.Gas90ProzentInMeter.Value)),
    LeerlaufInProzent = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisSekunden)) * x.Sum(y => y.LeerlaufInSekunden.Value),
    VerbrauchLiterAufHundertKm = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter)) * x.Sum(y => y.VerbrauchInLiter.Value) * 1000,
    RollenKmAufHundertKm = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter)) * x.Sum(y => y.RollenInMeter.Value),
    TempomatKmAufHundertKm = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter)) * x.Sum(y => y.TempomatInMeter.Value),
    GeschwindigkeitsuebertretungenAnzahlAufHundertKm = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter)) * 1000 * x.Sum(y => y.UebertretungenAnzahl.Value),
    GangwechselAnzahlAufHundertKm = (100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter)) * 1000 * x.Sum(y => y.GangwechselAnzahl.Value)
});
```

As you can see this part is repeated several times **(100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter))**.

In Linq to Objects it feels naturally to first project into an anonymous class to calculate the factor to avoid repetitive calculations. Like this:

```
.GroupBy(x => x.FahrerID)
.Select(x => new
{
    Grouping = x,
    BasisMeterFaktor = 100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter),
    BasisSekundenFaktor = 100m /x.Sum(y => y.BasisSekunden)
})
.Select(x => new FahrerligaEintrag()
{
    FahrerID = x.Grouping.Key,
    FahrerFullName = string.Empty,
    VollgasKmAufHundertKm = x.BasisMeterFaktor * (x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.Gas100ProzentInMeter.Value) + x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.Gas90ProzentInMeter.Value)),
    LeerlaufInProzent = x.BasisSekundenFaktor * x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.LeerlaufInSekunden.Value),
    VerbrauchLiterAufHundertKm = x.BasisMeterFaktor * x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.VerbrauchInLiter.Value) * 1000,
    RollenKmAufHundertKm = x.BasisMeterFaktor * x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.RollenInMeter.Value),
    TempomatKmAufHundertKm = x.BasisMeterFaktor * x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.TempomatInMeter.Value),
    GeschwindigkeitsuebertretungenAnzahlAufHundertKm = x.BasisMeterFaktor * 1000 * x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.UebertretungenAnzahl.Value),
    GangwechselAnzahlAufHundertKm = x.BasisMeterFaktor * 1000 * x.Grouping.Sum(y => y.GangwechselAnzahl.Value)
});
```

However, in LinqToEntities this results in poor performing SQL code. At least with this Oracle backend that I use (and which I can't profile to actually show me the SQL). So, I wonder if there is another way to avoid the repetitive calculations or if this is just the fastest that I can get.

Excuse all those German variable names. I'm sure you still get the meaning.

**UPDATE**

I was able to use ToTraceString() as suggested. Interestingly with the projection the SQL contains 18 (!!!) SELECT statements. Without it, it contains only 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I'd add this here and not just on twitter directly to Christoph. I think that's a lot to ask of LINQ to translate. Yes it can be done, but as he can see, it's not pretty because LINQ to Entities has to use generic algorithms to handle whatever you throw at it. If he's got the possibility of adding a stored proc or view to teh database, I'd go that route instead.

And I also recommended (the best I could in 140 chars) that he check out EFProfiler (efprof.com) or LLBLGen's new profiler (llblgen.com) for profiling EF queries in Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Does `.ToTraceString()` executed on the query provides a SQL query that you can profile? It's easy to get lost in all those calculations, but I'm sure, that if you want to all those calculations in a single query that the performance will suffer. Another way to decrease repetition with calculations is using the `let` keyword (there isn't a extension-method for it, so you have to use "traditional" LINQ). This "lets" you assign a variable that can be re-used in the query. But I doubt that it will perform any better than your grouping-approach.

```
from f in Fahrer
let meterFaktor = 100m / x.Sum(y =>.BasisMeter)
select new FahrerLigaEintrag()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "Let" is just query syntax sugar and translates down to a Select() projection. The compiler doesn't know about the query syntax at all. It all gets down to extension methods on a compiler level. However I was able to use ToTraceString() as you suggested. I don't know, I tried to use it months ago and had no luck but now it might works due to an update of the underlying devart oracle driver. The sql looks terrible but I'm trying to investigate it further. Unfortunately I can't post it here.

Comment: I updated the question. It turns out that the SQL is getting far more complicated with the projection in place. Not sure if there is another way to solve it in one query though.

Comment: @Christoph I can't see how removing the projections would decrease the amount of SELECTs to 2, since you need one for every .Sum(). What about putting every .Sum() call into a projection? I don't think you gain much performance from that, but at least it gives a clearer overview of all involved properties. I've counted 10 .Sum()s which is a lot though.

Comment: It decreases to 2 selects because there is no need to do a SELECT in the first place as Sum() is a natural aggregation method in a SQL Groupy By operator. However, with the projection in place he does not rely on that but instead uses one sub select for each aggregation.

Comment: @Christoph the query might be more "complex" but performance is the question, is it not? Have you compared the two queries?

Comment: @DustinDavis sure, its 40 times (!!!) slower with the more complex query in place. However, I realized that I should create a server side view for this performance critical part.

Answer (score 0):

What about using generic delegate `Func<Tx, Ty, TResult>`?

```
// declare out of query and provide valid types for x, y, result
Func<TX, TY, TResult> basisMeterFaktorAlgo;

// set formula once
basisMeterFaktorAlgo = (x, y) => 100m / x.Sum(y => y.BasisMeter);

// call it in query
basicMeterFactor = basisMeterFaktorAlgo(xValue, yValue)
```

Comment: How should that be translated to SQL. I'm confused.

Comment: @Christoph : looks like I missed something since a title containe `Linq to Entities` (to objects?)

Comment: The whole query is build up against in IQueryable. The IQueryableProvider takes care of converting the expression tree into a proper SQL query. So any refactoring must result into a query that the IQueryableProvider can translate into proper SQL.

Comment: In this case 'Im not sure how this would be translated to SQL, can you give it a try?